# Filters and validators are added twice

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I wrote about it on [zf2 github](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5166) and no one answered yet. But maybe it's not a bug and I'm doing something wrong. Here is my code:

Fieldset

```
class TestFieldset extends Fieldset implements
    InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'test'
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification() {
        return array(
            'test' => array(
                'filters' => array(
                    array('name' => 'StringTrim')
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array('name' => 'NotEmpty')
                )
            )
        );
    } 
}
```

Form

```
class TestForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array()) {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $fieldset = new TestFieldset('test-fieldset');

        $this->add($fieldset);
    }
}
```

Controller action

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new \CRM\Form\TestForm;    
    $form->setData(array('test-fieldset' => array('test' => 'test value')));
    $form->isValid();

    $inputFilter = $form->getInputFilter()
            ->get('test-fieldset')
            ->get('test');

    $filters = $inputFilter->getFilterChain()
        ->getFilters();

    $validators = $inputFilter->getValidatorChain()
        ->getValidators();

    var_dump($filters);
    var_dump($validators);
}
```

Result

```
object(Zend\Stdlib\PriorityQueue)[678]
  protected 'queueClass' => string 'Zend\Stdlib\SplPriorityQueue' (length=28)
  protected 'items' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => 
            object(Zend\Filter\StringTrim)[682]
              ...
          'priority' => int 1000
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'data' => 
            object(Zend\Filter\StringTrim)[693]
              ...
          'priority' => int 1000
  protected 'queue' => 
    object(Zend\Stdlib\SplPriorityQueue)[683]
      protected 'serial' => int 2147483645
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'instance' => 
        object(Zend\Validator\NotEmpty)[686]
          protected 'constants' => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          protected 'messageTemplates' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'options' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'value' => string 'test value' (length=10)
          protected 'abstractOptions' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
      'breakChainOnFailure' => boolean false
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'instance' => 
        object(Zend\Validator\NotEmpty)[697]
          protected 'constants' => 
            array (size=13)
              ...
          protected 'messageTemplates' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
          protected 'options' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          protected 'value' => string 'test value' (length=10)
          protected 'abstractOptions' => 
            array (size=7)
              ...
      'breakChainOnFailure' => boolean false
```

As you can see, there are two StringTrim filters and two NotEmpty validators. It's annoying especially when I'm using File\RenameUpload filter and it's trying to rename and move already renamed file.

Comment: Couldn't find where it is duplicating input filters and validators, but try removing function `getInputFilterSpecification()` from TestFieldset and do this in it's construct:
    $this->add(array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'name' => 'test',
        'filters' => array(
            array('name' => 'string_trim'),
        ),
        'validators' => array(
            array('name' => 'not_empty'),
        ),
    ));
Than check if it is still duplicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was fixed in zf 2.2.5 https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5270